# extjs - Roweditor not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I have a gridPanel defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.winbiz.ExportGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: 'winbiz.Exports',
    plugins: [{ptype: 'rowediting', clicksToMoveEditor: 2, autoCancel: false}],
    columns: [
        {text: 'Id',  dataIndex: 'id'},
        {
            text: 'Description', 
            dataIndex: 'description', 
            flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I have this problem with the rowEditing plugin:
Instead of editing the line on which I double-click, a new row is inserted at the top of the grid, but it does not show the editor fields.

I looked everywhere in the code and compared to a [working example based on the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/direct_grid_pt2), but I cannot find what is not correct.

This is how it looks like: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the rowEditor did not work was the following:

I have a custom template. The css needed for the rowEditiong plugin to work was not included.

Once I rebuilt the application with `sencha app build` the css file was updated and everything worked fine.

Comment: I was not using custom templates, but only after `sencha app build` the RowEditor worked. Thank you very much for sharing this solution.
(I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
    {
        text: 'Description', 
        dataIndex: 'description', 
        flex:1,
        editor: { 
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: true // (or false)
        }               
    }
....
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion, but it does not help. I also added a screenshot.

Comment: Was "description" field filled by server/store data? If not, there may be problem with calling editor for this field with property "allowBlank:false". I see all "description" fields are empty in whole grid. Try to set allowBlank:true. Although, I do not think that's the reason.